# regression quality with meta score using R2 and MAE for optimisation

Tags: regression, optimization, hyperparameter-tuning

Considering quality of regression models I currently try to compare two types of information:

1. The $R^2$ score that give me the information about the tendency of the predictor
2. The $MAE$ (or $RMSE$) error to know how much data are far from the $R^2$ line.

A perfect match gives a $R^2$ = 1 and MAE = 0.

As a result a meta_score like this  could be a minimize target:

meta_score = abs(1-r2_score(y_true-y_pred))+MAE

BUT in this formulation $MAE$ and $R^2$ are not equally considered because $R^2$ is supposed to be $\lt 1$ whereas there is no limit to $MAE$.

Optimizing a regressor means that both $R^2$ and $MAE$ are optimized. Is there a manner to properly consider both, combined in a single estimator? Actually, I consider a $R^2$ optimization then I read the $MAE$. But it does not sounds good because we are ignoring half of the quality indicator...

Thank you for your insight!

Comment: Actually $R^2$ in direct relation with RMSE, so optimizing after $R^2$ and RMSE does not makes sense. An idea perhaps would be to build a score for MAE in a similar way like $R^2$ for RMSE ($R_{MAE} = 1 - \frac{MAE_{residuals}}{MAE_y}$) and optimize on the sum of $R^2$ and $R_{MAE}$. You can even weight a proportion between them?

Comment: Maximizing $R^2$ is the same as minimizing $RMSE$, so you could consider some kind of combination of $RMSE$ and $MAE$, though I do not understand your need to combine the two. It might help solve your problem if you say what your goals are.